# Number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points on a smooth variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

From the proof of Weil's conjectures it follows that
$|q^k - \# X(\mathbb{F}_{q^k})| = O(q^{k(n - \frac{1}{2})})$, where
$X$ is a smooth variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $n = \dim X$ (see for example http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf). How the constant in $O(\ldots)$ can be estimated?

Every estimation  (even very rough) is interesting.

Comment: I would think that something could be said in terms of, e.g. Betti numbers of $X$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Betti numbers is appeared if $X$ is a reduction of some (good) projective variety - not in general case, isn't it?